# How to read formatted file in Python array

Tags: python, arrays, input

I need to read data from a file that's formatted like this:

```
  0.00000  62.12404   0.00000
  1.95695  62.12288   0.00000
  3.91389  62.11939   0.00000
  5.87084  62.11357   0.00000
  7.82779  62.10543   0.00000
  9.78474  62.09496   0.00000
 11.74168  62.08218   0.00000
 13.69863  62.06707   0.00000
```

(the script that produces the data specifies the format as "%9.5f").The number of lines isn't fixed and I want to have either an 3xN array or 3 arrays of length N at the end. Normally i'd use `lines.split` but that doesn't really work if the number of spaces between the numbers isn't fixed.

Comment: You could strip each line, replace multiple spaces with a single space and then use split.

Comment: Try reading this as a CSV with delimiter space

Comment: What python version are you using? In 3.6 input with multiple spaces in between like `'   23   545    345   '.split()` returns `['23', '545', '345']`

Comment: @Szymon I'm using 3.4, but if i just use `split()`  like this: `array = np.zeros((len(lines),3))
for i in range (len(lines)):
    array[i,:]=(lines[i].split())` I just get ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 0 to array axis with dimension 3

Comment: Then you probably have an empty line (or multiple)  at the end of the file. Filter those out and it will work.

Answer (score 6):

## The elegant way:

You can read the file using `pandas.read_csv` method ([link to the documentation page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)).
Using an existing module that has been widely tested, documented, and used should always be the first option to be considered to accomplish any task.

**Note**: *You can handle several consecutive spaces using `sep='\s+'`*

## The ugly way (reinventing the wheel):

`split` method from str class can handle several consecutive spaces.

> If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace. Consequently, splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace with a None separator returns [].

[Reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("data.txt", "r") as data:
    [line.split() for line in data]
```

I tested in python 2.7 and python 3.5. It should work

Answer (score 1):

split should be works in python 2 and 3 :

```
>>> str = '  0.00000  62.12404   0.00000'
>>> print str.split()
['0.00000', '62.12404', '0.00000']
```

You can also try with regex :

```
print re.split('\s{1,}', str.strip())
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. When iterating through the lines and using `array[i,:]=(lines[i].split())`  I get "ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 0 to array axis with dimension 3" as an error. lines is genereated through this: `lines = text_file.read().split('\n')` and array is an array with the domensions len(lines) and 3

Comment: check the solution of @lukas herman, its a clean way to do it. You can also check what is an intention list in python to understand it !

Comment: I found my error, i iterated 1 step too much so that i ended up assigning an empty object to the last field of the array. Your solution works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

data.txt  contains your data

```
file_object  = open("data.txt", "r")

mylist = list()

while True:
    a = file_object.readline().split()
    if a is None or len(a) == 0 or a is EOFError:
        break
    else:
       mylist.append(a)

for a in mylist:
    print(a)
```

this code gives the result below

```
['0.00000', '62.12404', '0.00000']
['1.95695', '62.12288', '0.00000']
['3.91389', '62.11939', '0.00000']
['5.87084', '62.11357', '0.00000']
['7.82779', '62.10543', '0.00000']
['9.78474', '62.09496', '0.00000']
['11.74168', '62.08218', '0.00000']
['13.69863', '62.06707', '0.00000']
```